# sorting data labels on an R chart

Tags: r, sorting, graph

I'm just starting to learn how to use R and am following online tutorials. I have got as far as creating a sorted, circular plotted bar graph, but now I want to add data labels.
I can't figure out how to sort the labels so they appear over the right bars.
Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  id=seq(1,11),
  name=AllMyLego$`Grouped Themes`,
  value=AllMyLego$`Minifigs`
)

label_data <- data
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <- 90-360*(label_data$id-0.5)/number_of_bar
label_data$hjust<-ifelse(angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

data %>%
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, value)) %>%

  ggplot( aes(x=name, y=value)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=alpha("dark green",0.5)) +
    ylim(-50,280)+
    theme_minimal()+
    theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
         axis.title = element_blank(),
         panel.grid = element_blank(),
         plot.margin = unit(rep(-2,4),"cm"))+
    coord_polar(start=0)+

geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=value+10, label=name, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE )
```

this produces a chart that looks like this:

[image: chart with wrong labels]

I've tried running mutate() against the label_data data as well as against the id field alone but am not proving successful. Sadly the online tutorial I'm following doesn't include how the labels were sorted on their example.
Can anyone set me straight on this please?

here is the data that I am working with:

```
AllMyLego <- structure(list(`Grouped Themes` = structure(1:11, .Label = c("City", 
"Dimensions", "Film and TV", "Ideas", "Lego Movies", "Ninjago", 
"Other", "Pirates", "Seasonal", "Star Wars", "Super Heroes"), class = "factor"), 
    Minifigs = c(105L, 9L, 22L, 9L, 57L, 154L, 49L, 11L, 39L, 
    255L, 67L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L
))
```

thanks
Keith

Comment: Hi Keith. This should be a straightforward fix if you can share your data. Without that, we would have to try to reconstruct a similar data set, which is likely to just cause confusion. Could you type `dput(AllMyLego)` into your console and copy the output from the console, then use the gray "edit" link beneath your question and paste the result into your question in a code block?

Comment: @AllanCameron I've added data to the question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```r
label_data <- data
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
label_data <- label_data %>% mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, value))
angle <- 90-360 * (order(order(label_data$name)) - 0.5) / number_of_bar
label_data$hjust <- ifelse(angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle + 180, angle)

data %>%
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = alpha("dark green", 0.5)) +
    ylim(-50, 280)+
    theme_void() +
    coord_polar(start = 0, direction = 1) +
    geom_text(data = label_data, aes(x = name, y = value + 10, 
                                     label = name, hjust = hjust), 
          color = "black", fontface = "bold",alpha = 0.6, size = 2.5, 
          angle = label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Note that the most important things were using `x = name` in the `aes` inside `geom_text`. This also meant working out the order the labels are going to be plotted beforehand.